# How to hide the remaining buttons when user clicks a button and shows the respective message

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, single-page-application, ngroute

I am trying to develop a single page web application.In my Welcome.html i had several buttons.when user clicks a button all buttons should vanish and the respective message or any content respective to the clicked button should appear in place of that my

Welcome.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Film Management System</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>

<body background='bg1.JPG'>
<img src='bg.png' width="1270" height="222"/>

<a href="#/AddNewFilm" class="addfilm_buttton button1">Add New Film</a>
<a href="#/ModifyFilm" class="modifyfilm_buttton button1">Modify Existing Film</a>

<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my app.js is

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider

      .when('/AddNewFilm', {
        templateUrl : 'AddNewFilm.html',
        controller  : 'AddNewFilm'
      })

      .when('/ModifyFilm', {
        templateUrl : 'ModifyFilm.html',
        controller  : 'ModifyFilm'
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    });

app.controller('AddNewFilm', function($scope) {
      $scope.message = 'Hello from AddNewFilm';
    });


app.controller('ModifyFilm', function($scope) {
      $scope.message = 'Hello from ModifyFilm';
    });
```

AddNewFilm.html

```
<div align="center">
<h1>AddNewFilm</h1>
<h3>{{message}}</h3>
</div>
```

ModifyFilm.html

```
<div align="center">
<h1>ModifyFilm</h1>     
<h3>{{message}}</h3>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: post a working fiddle, so i can edit that

Comment: what working fiddle? ,i can not get you@Guti

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mkq7q4so/
write all of your code here, so i can see it in action

Comment: add jsfiddle link to your question, or add a comment with that link

Comment: @RaghuRamMullapudi if you want to hide the buttons how would you navigate to another page you have to go back  again

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/raghurammullapudi44/v5tkmov5/  @Guti

Comment: @SusheelSingh i will add a home button

Comment: where is the home button in your question. can you add that

Comment: @Guti does my link is it available to you

Comment: you can have div around the buttons with `ng-hide` directive. By default make it false in home page. When you click on the button make it true in the controller. Ths way it will hide the button

Comment: i dont know if this is what you were looking or not.
Anyways please check the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mkq7q4so/4/

Comment: it Works Thank you,@Guti

Comment: @Guti please check this fiddle link,the output is not as expected please correct me where i am gone wrong https://jsfiddle.net/raghurammullapudi44/wpaL4qjb/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gfaf89p5/
here is another working fiddle.
Define your controller as
app.controller('ctrlname', function(){});

Comment: yes thank you @Guti,it helped me a lot